# Python string decode socket error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, runtime-error

When I was trying to decode a string sent from the client, I received the error "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff" (using Python3).

Error:

data received: b'STORE Domingos 2018_07_26:09_33_15.jpg\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01.....

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 38: invalid start byte

Code:
(USER is a normal string)

```
#Server
data = conn.recv(1024)
data = data.decode("utf8").rstrip()

#Client
message = 'STORE ' + USER + ' ' + file
message = message.encode('utf-8')
s.send(message)
```

Comment: What are `USER` and `file`?

Comment: Please always include code and errors as text, not in the form of screenshots.

Comment: Your screenshot let think that file could be the content of a JPEG file. You should give some context about what you are trying to achieve because you are probably using a wrong way. **Without knowing what USER and file are, I cannot help**

Comment: I'm trying to send a string, so the server knows what to do next. "store" o save to user "Domingos", and the file name. And then send the .jpg file.

Comment: This is not a socket error. It is a decoder error. Be precise. Not sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was later in the code.
    conn.recv (1024)

Upon receiving the string the "recv" did not pass the front and receives unwanted information.

I solved the problem in sending a confirmation string, to the client, after receiving the string.

Answer (score 0):

`0xff` is illegal to use in UTF-8 see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) you have to filter it out before decoding it. You could use this:

```
data1 = data.decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
```

Update: You are trying to decode a Jpg file to UTF-8 that does not work.

Comment: i already try all types of error parameters. receive the same error but with unknown characters. Domingos/2018_07_26:09_42_12.jpg����JFIFHH��c�ExifMM*
�